# Running an Ansible loop in reverse

Tags: ansible

I am working on an ansible playbook and in one play I am trying to removing some nodes using my own module (NodeModule) using UUID. All nodes is a list that has UUID of the nodes.

```
- name: Remove OSNs
  NodeModule:
    connection:
      ip: "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    action: remove_node
    id: "{{ all_nodes[(item)] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(0, all_nodes|length, 1)|list }}"
```

This works perfectly if I delete it in forward order. How can I run my "Loop" in reverse order ? I want to start deleting the nodes in reverse. Tried something like this but it doesn't work

```
loop: "{{ range(all_nodes|length, 0, -1)|list }}"
```

Even tried this but its fails too

```
Loop: "{{ range(0, all_nodes|length, 1)|reverse|list }}"
```

Could not find anything in Ansible document that address reverse looping.

Answer (score 5):

Q: ***"How can I run my loop in reverse order?"***

A: Use the filter [*reverse*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.reverse). For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    all_nodes: [eth0, eth1, eth2]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ all_nodes|reverse }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  item: eth2
  item: eth1
  item: eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this snippet will be for you:

```
- set_fact:
    arr:
      - a
      - b
      - c
      - d
      - e
    ke: "{{ range(5, 0, -1) | list }}"   

- name: reverse
  debug: msg="{{arr[item-1]}}"
  loop: "{{ke}}"
```